# Questões sobre VHDL são permitidas?

Tags: debate

O VHDL é uma linguagem de descrição de hardware. Bem, até onde eu (pouco) sei, ele é usado em CPLD, FPGA e ASIC. Enfim, ela não é uma linguagem de programação o que me leva a crer que estaria fora dos assuntos abrangidos pelo SOpt, *praticamente*.

Pesquisando um pouco vi que grande parte das perguntas usando a *tag* de VHDL no SO [são negativadas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl), o que me chamou atenção. No SOpt não tem qualquer pergunta, nem existe esta *tag* por aqui. Mas, já existe essa questão [no Meta do SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322363/why-do-i-get-a-down-vote-on-every-vhdl-question-i-ask/322427#322427), mas não aqui no SOpt.

Para complementar tudo, esta mesma *tag* de VHDL também está no [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl), o que não tem nada haver com o StackOverflow.

---

Isso me leva a duas perguntas:

1. Perguntas sobre (ou usando) VHDL são permitidas no SOpt?
2. Existe interesse em responder questões sobre isso aqui no SOpt?

Comment: Não é linguagem de programação? Parece que é usada assim, sim. HTML é linguagem de programação. [Não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101). Eu acho que é *on*. Os negativos a gente precisa ver se é por estarem mal feitas ou porque a pessoa negativou sem saber o que é aquilo. Acho improvável ter muitas pessoas que respondam, mas se conseguir chamá-las seria muito bom.

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown.

Comment: Um [primeiro teste](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216032/5878) de como será recebida aqui.

Comment: Eu acho até mais válido e pertinente do que [tag:code-golf], sendo que eu acho isso pertinente também

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eu acho válido - mas sou suspeito em dizer isso já que VHDL tem sido a minha principal linguagem nos últimos 5 anos.

**Por quê eu acho válido?**

Da mesma forma que muitos percebem que estudar Assembly faz a pessoa aprender melhor como as linguagens de programação funcionam, eu considero que estudar VHDL faz com que a pessoa entenda como o *hardware* em si funciona. Não é linguagem de programação, como dito, mas o escopo do SOpt não é limitado à elas, a citar o HTML, CSS e LaTeX, que não são linguagens de programação e fazem parte do escopo.

Um dos "problemas" que vejo é que o público do VHDL é muito pequeno. Não só aqui no SOpt, no país como um todo. Serão poucas as pessoas que conseguirão participar ativamente de uma discussão sobre o assunto. Embora acho que isso não seja um problema limitante e que é possível contorná-lo. Eu mesmo já cogitei em elaborar algumas perguntas sobre VHDL e respondê-las por mim mesmo para tentar difundir melhor a linguagem entre aqueles que a desconhecem. É uma ideia ainda em análise, principalmente por não saber exatamente quão bem recebidas essas perguntas seriam. A atual discussão possivelmente responderá isso.

**Respondendo...**

> Perguntas sobre (ou usando) VHDL são permitidas no SOpt?

Acredito que sim. Não há um tópico muito claro sobre isso na definição do escopo do site, mas acho que a comunidade tem mais a ganhar do que perder nesses casos.

> Existe interesse em responder questões sobre isso aqui no SOpt?

Eu tenho, pelo menos.

Comment: Já temos pelo menos um expert, já deve dar para responder a muitas perguntas :)

Answer (score 9):

> Questões sobre VHDL são permitidas?

Sim.

> ela não é uma linguagem de programação

Falso. Ela é sim uma linguagem de programação. O que ocorre é que o processo de compilação do VHDL pode incluir a criação de um circuito eletrônico digital. Entretanto, frequentemente você executa o que foi criado em um simulador.

Ora, se nela você codifica alguma coisa que vai ser executada em algum lugar (mesmo que num simulador), então VHDL é de fato uma linguagem de programação.

Além disso, VHDL tem construções tais como variáveis, procedimentos, funções, repetição, if, etc. Ela tem uma estrutura algorítmica típica de linguagens de programação, embora o estilo seja bem diferente uma vez que o propósito é bem diferente.

E mesmo se VHDL não fosse linguagem de programação, CSS e HTML não são e mesmo assim estão fortemente dentro do escopo deste site.

Assim, chegamos a resposta desses seus questionamentos:

> Perguntas sobre (ou usando) VHDL são permitidas no SOpt?

Sim.

> Existe interesse em responder questões sobre isso aqui no SOpt?

Se houver quem possa responder essas questões, sim. Pela resposta do Anderson Carlos Woss, já temos ao menos um especialista por aqui, e um que já tem um grande número de pontos de reputação acumulados neste site.

Comment: Victor, achei muito interessante seu ponto de vista. Creio que merece ter lugar ao sol na [pergunta seminal sobre VHDL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216032/5878) =]