# Podemos ter uma Area 51 de determinado conteúdo no Meta para definir o escopo?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

É comum termos discussões sobre se um determinado assunto faz ou não parte do escopo do Stack Overflow em Português. Alguns são facilmente analisados por serem em quase sua totalidade parte do escopo ou não. Outros parecem que parte faz parte do escopo enquanto outra parte não.

- A discussão sobre VHDL ([Questões sobre VHDL são permitidas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6124/5878)) pareceu não gerar dúvidas e foi assumido como parte do escopo;
- A discussão sobre matemática ([Matemática básica faz parte do escopo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7731/5878)) está até hoje em aberto porque notou-se que é basicamente caso a caso; há perguntas que são [muito bem aceitas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239450/5878), enquanto já houveram outras que foram fechadas.
- O caso mais recente é a discussão sobre Docker ([Docker está no nosso escopo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7943/5878)), com maior participação, porém ainda em aberto, inicialmente pendendo também para o caso a caso;

Para facilitar a compreensão da comunidade sobre assuntos mais complicados de tomar uma decisão definitiva, como matemática e Docker, podemos criar uma Área 51 aqui no Meta para cada assunto, em formato de pergunta dentro do próprio Meta?

Minha sugestão inicial:

1. A pergunta deverá seguir o mesmo padrão da [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/5878)

   - O título deverá ser algo como: "Quais perguntas devem fazer parte do nosso escopo em relação a X?", sendo X o assunto abordado;
   - Deve apresentar uma breve descrição da motivação que levou abrir a pergunta;
   - Se existir, deve adicionar o link da discussão no Meta que originou a pergunta (desejável);
   - Deve possuir uma lista para os tópicos já aprovados através das respostas, sendo cada item da lista um link para a respectiva resposta;
2. Cada sugestão de pergunta deve ser uma nova resposta;

   - Deve ser apresentado um exemplo de como seria a pergunta se ela fosse publicada no Stack Overflow em Português;
   - Se necessário, deve conter uma descrição de quais são as peculiaridades daquela pergunta dentro do assunto discutido;

     - Exemplo: "Pergunta: Como calcular a integral do seno? Peculiaridade: A pergunta aborda apenas o aspecto matemático da discussão, não aspectos de implementação em código da solução"
   - Cada usuário poderá votar positivamente se concordar que aquele exemplo de pergunta faria parte do escopo; ou negativamente se discordar;
   - Cada usuário poderá utilizar os comentários da resposta para argumentar porque considera com escopo ou não;
3. Uma sugestão de pergunta é definida como dentro do escopo quando a quantidade de votos positivos na resposta for muito superior à quantidade de votos negativos (seria interessante ter uma regra muito bem definida para isso, tal como (exemplo) a resposta possuir no mínimo 15 votos no total e a quantidade de positivos for pelo menos o triplo de negativos, +12/-3);
4. (Opcional) Assim como existiria na pergunta uma lista com as sugestões aprovadas poderia existir uma outra lista com sugestões negadas e uma sugestão entraria nessa lista se ela satisfizesse inversamente a regra definida em (3), por exemplo, ficar +3/-12.

Ter algo assim no Meta teria duas vantagens principais, ao meu ver:

1. Clarificar a discussão sobre quais partes de um assunto podem ou não fazer parte do escopo, de modo que não precisamos permitir, nem proibir, por completo tal assunto; por ventura, isso servirá de base para decidirmos se o assunto é, no geral, parte do escopo ou não ao verificar que todas as sugestões dadas estão sendo aprovadas/negadas;
2. Servir de base nos fechamentos das perguntas no Stack Overflow em Português, pois uma vez que uma sugestão é negada no Meta, dentro desta "pergunta área 51", todas as perguntas semelhantes abertas no site poderão ser fechadas citando a "resposta área 51" que possui a sugestão negada;

Acham que algo assim funcionaria? Alguém possui alguma sugestão de alteração na estrutura ou vê algum problema gritante que inviabilizaria testarmos isso?

Comment: Eu não acho viável. O Meta do site mal tem participação, imagina um Meta específico para definir escopos do site.

Comment: @CypherPotato Meta específico? Não, é uma pergunta nesse Meta...

Comment: @CypherPotato, é uma pergunta tal essa aqui [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic) só que em vez de apenas sugerir um tópico o AR sugere e defende o porque dessa tecnologia deva fazer parte do escopo.

Comment: Exato. Cada resposta da pergunta seria um exemplo de pergunta que estaria no SOpt. Os votos nessa resposta seriam se concorda ou discorda se aquele tipo de pergunta poderia ser feita no site. A ideia é reconhecer quais são os formatos permitidos para o escopo dentro de um assunto em discussão.

Comment: Ontem a noite eu fiz essa pesquisa no google [About Portuguese Stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=about+portuguese+stackoverflow&oq=about+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l2j69i60l2.3244j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) e descobri a luta que foi para criar o StackOverflow em Português e Fato do PTSO ter **nascido de uma Area51**. Se minha opinião vale de alguma coisa então eu me manifesto favorável a ideia de uma *Area51*, pois só estou aqui manifestando minha opinião graças a uma *Area51*.

Comment: Não creio que vá funcionar de forma alguma, muitos dos interessados que apresentam conhecimento satisfatório para opinar não frequentam tanto o site (além dos que só querem por querer e por usar, mas não entendem profundamente o assunto), no começo pode ter parecer bom, mas logo vai ter resultados insatisfatórios, o próprio https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/3635 teve boas sugestões, mas teve uma enxurrada de coisas que "fugiam" muito. Não estou dizendo que é uma má ideia, só dizendo que vai faltar interesse de quem entende do novos assuntos X e vai ter muito apoio de quem entende pouco.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Mas acha isso inviabiliza testarmos?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acredito que não impeça em nada, afinal as coisas podem mudar ou até surgir ideias de como atrair o publico necessário, mas ainda creio que somado a uma série de experiências parecidas (no meta mesmo) e falta de interesse de quem tem o "conhecimento técnico" sobre cada "novo assunto/tópico" participar as chances disto falhar são altar