# Qual o criterio para suspender questões por parte dos moderadores

Tags: debate

Nos últimos tempos tenho assistido a um comportamento que me parece um pouco excessivo por parte dos moderadores do site que vão fechando ou marcando como pendentes questões em várias questões em vês muitas vezes de tentarem entender o seu enquadramento e ajudarem quem pergunta.

Pessoalmente enquanto o criador da Tag [Primaverabss], já agora que uma empresa de tecnologia que produz software de gestão, tenho visto muitas questões a serem marcadas como pendentes com a indicação de que está fora do âmbito do site, mas são questões de programação que podem estar no limite mal formatadas porque os utilizadores são novos, e neste caso é necessário ajuda-los a perceber a dinâmica.

Um exemplo:

- [Icons das aplicações no PRIMAVERA Administrator Extensibility [pendente]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/413531/icons-das-aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-primavera-administrator-extensibility)

Esta questão que está formatada, bem formulada, é sobre programação está marcada fora do ambito do site porque?

Não estarão os moderadores a ser exigentes demais?

Comment: No meu ver, o problema foi o oposto, a moderação foi muito tolerante no início, tentando fazer dar certo a experiência de aceitar um produto específico de nicho no escopo do site (não que o produto seja o problema, e sim o fato de atrair uma comunidade muito ocasional que não domina o padrão do site) - Agora que os critérios normais estão sendo mais corretamente aplicados, pode estar dando essa impressão dada a diferença da situação anterior. - De qualquer forma, o debate no META é bem vindo (apesar de eu achar que com um tom desnecessário), e a comunidade como um todo pode se manifestar.

Comment: "*[...] mas são questões de programação que podem estar no limite mal formatadas*", então o fechamento foi correto. No final da mensagem do motivo de fechamento você até pode ver um "Melhore a pergunta", que inclusive é um link para uma página que auxiliará os usuários novos.

Comment: A tag [primaverabss] tem se mostrado especialmente problemática, porque 95% das perguntas criadas com ela são ruins e as outras 5% somente uma pessoa pode responder (e é bem comum a resposta ser: "era bug, estamos resolvendo"). Neste caso, a tag se resume mais a interesse da empresa do que da comunidade. Na minha opinião ela não funcionou e poderia ser removida.

Comment: E que fique claro que isso não significa "Não gostamos de vocês", mas sim um "Desse jeito não deu muito certo com a proposta de repositório de conhecimento no formato Q&A do site". Me parece mais um problema de ferramenta × conteúdo incompatíveis do que "algum lado estar errado".

Comment: Agradeço o feedback de todos, e não quero de forma alguma colocar em causa a moderação do site.

Comment: A PRIMAVERA possui uma grande comunidade de programadores em Portugal, Africa e outros paises de expressão portuguesa, e tem vido a creçer cada vez mais. Dito isto:
Reconheço que existe um defice de conhecimento das regras de site, e temos feito um exforço para educar esta comunidade.
Temos sempre que possivel indicado que o stack não é uma área de suporte tradicional mas um site de Q&A.

Comment: E uma sugestão: não ficou claro se o problema é o comportamento da moderação ou o fechamento supostamente errado. Se for sobre a moderação, eu recomendaria você a listar mais casos que mostram que é um comportamento constante e não um caso isolado. Se for sobre o fechamento, recomendaria que focasse apenas nisso e descrevesse porque julga equivocado o fechamento. Erros acontecem e podem ser revertidos

Comment: E se o formato do SO atende às necessidades da Primavera, eu recomendaria o uso do https://stackoverflow.com/teams.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é do fecho estar na minha opinião errado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Já usamos o teams para as equipas internas da PRIMAVERA, este é para a nossa comunidade de programadores, para todos os que desenvolvem com a nossa tecnologia. Acho que está certo não?

Comment: Questão: Somos ou um TAG valida para o site...apesar da tecnologia ser restrita a um grupo de pessoas? Este é um criterio valido?

Comment: @SérgioSereno Acho que isso é discussão para outra pergunta no Meta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Vou abrir. Obrigado a todos pelos inputs.~

Comment: Esta aqui acredito que o Maniero seria a melhor pessoa a justificar o fechamento.

Comment: E provavelmente a [primaverabss] seria outra tag que poderia se beneficiar da [Área 51](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7979/5878) no meta.

Comment: Caro Sérgio, reforço dizendo, FECHADO (ou Pendente) não é a mesma coisa que "banida para sempre", é só fechado e pode ser reaberto, leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635

Comment: @Guilherme sim, eu sei disso, a questão em caso já esta esclarecida.

Comment: Caro Sérgio, que bom, só adicionei aqui porque foi um grande esforço na época em formular aquela resposta do outro link no META, detalhei como agir em cada tipo de fechamento, se isso lhe interessar, assim como pode interessar a visitantes da sua pergunta atual saber como agir em cada tipo de fechamento, se tiver calma e tempo leia com paciência que vai notar os tais detalhes

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento obrigado já tive a oportunidade de ler e irei usar para passar aos novos usuários da tag. Está muito bem resumido.

Comment: @Maniero adicionei esta secção de faq ao site dos developers primavera para ajudar que está na comunidade https://developers.primaverabss.com/faqs/?faq_filter=216

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O critério já está na tarja amarela e nos *links* contidos nela. Além disso tudo foi debatido aqui no site, em geral destacado no quadro amarelo à direita. Quem participa da comunidade sempre sabe dessas coisas. Quem aparece esporadicamente e não vê tudo o que ocorre fica confuso.

A pergunta em questão [foi fechada em outro contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/413531/revisions). Fico pensando se não é abusivo ignorar isto e reclamar de algo sem considerar este contexto. Quando foi fechada era muito pior. Agora melhorou mas não sei se está em bom estado. Na original faltava muita informação e era fácil fechar, agora eu não sei se fecharia, não consigo tomar uma decisão porque não conheço o assunto o suficiente pra saber se dá para responder **bem**. A impressão que eu tenho é que não dá, mas não afirmaria. Por isso também não sei se deve ser reaberta.

Em nenhum momento esta pergunta foi fechada por não está bem formatada, ou por não ser de programação. Foi fechada por ser mal formulada sim, e isto pode ser facilmente observável, eu só não sei se melhorou. Então quem está questionando o fechamento também pode ser questionada se consegue fazer boas avaliações sobre o fechamento.

Uma pergunta se é *bug* é por definição complicada de dar uma boa resposta, porque ela seria sim ou não. Caso seja um não, então poderia se dar uma solução, mas é uma pergunta aberta, dá margem para responder qualquer coisa. De uma certa forma é um faça para mim (ainda que não seja exatamente). É muito complicado lidar com uma pergunta deste tipo. E de fato mais recentemente começamos ser mais rígidos, com anuência da comunidade, porque perguntas assim começaram ser prevalentes e por isso passaram ser um problema. Quase sempre ficam sem resposta ou resposta que não ajudam ninguém, muitas vezes sendo um chute de como resolver.

Eu tenho quase certeza que a pessoa foi orientada fora do site a melhorar a pergunta. Será que não deveria resolver tudo fora?

Durante um período várias das perguntas desta *tag* ficaram sem respostas ou qualquer tentativa de fazer algo. Todas essas perguntas parecem questões de suporte que deveriam ser feitos em âmbito próprio e não parece ser de interesse da comunidade como um todo. Parece ser um caso de usar o [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams).

Não ajuda o fato das pessoas que poderiam se interessar mais por essas questões não participarem tão ativamente do site e não ajudar muito. Note que não tem um comentário ali.

Boa parte das respostas não ajudam ninguém além da pessoa que perguntou, que vai contra a filosofia do site, e muitas delas, é "realmente é um bug e estamos corrigindo", o que não é uma resposta e por isso a pergunta nem deveria estar ali. Boa parte das perguntas são ruins e causam ruído. Acho que está na hora de debatermos se a *tag* deveria permanecer no site.

O software não é aberto e não tem uma documentação aberta, quase ninguém pode testar ou se beneficiar disto, há uma limitação muito grande de quem pode responder e principalmente classificar as perguntas e respostas, uma premissa do site. E até dá uma margem para erros de moderadores.

Nestes casos eu prefiro errar por restringir mais que deve, a experiência com esta *tag* indica que acaba sendo mais acertado, quase tudo que se posta sobre o assunto é ruim. Há quem defenda que tudo deveria começar fechado e abrir quando é algo bom :)

O primeiro parágrafo tem presunções que fazem sentido, inclusive porque tenta colocar como algo não justificável e que aqui não há justificativas que deva ser o contrário, então todo o *post* e comentários parecem indicar ser só um desejo e não um debate.

Comment: Obrigado pela reflexão. 
Só uma nota existe documentação dedicada e o software é aberto. https://developers.primaverabss.com, repositórios Git: https://github.com/PrimaverabssDeveloper

Vou também estar mais vigilante sobre comentários como os referidos.

Comment: Isso ajuda. Isso é 100% aberto ou só uma API que ajuda acessar o software principal? É possível com isso se beneficiar de tudo? Me confirme isso pra mudar a resposta, o que seria um argumento a menos contra a *tag*.

Comment: Ok. Nem tudo está aberto, a core está fechado e é proprietário. Agora todos os programadores que usam a tecnologia podem adicionar interfaçes, alterar os existentes, alterar e criar regras, mudar toda a aplicação a sua vontade. Existe também partes todas 100% abertas como é caso desta aplicação https://github.com/PrimaverabssDeveloper/ERP10Mobile.

Comment: A resposta é clara? Mais uma coisa esta tag é para a comunidade developers fora sa empresa, por isso o teams não é solução, esse é usado pelas equipas internas.

Comment: A única forma de ter as próprias regras é ter o Teams para a comunidade. Já acostumaram em usar internamente, podem usar o Teams pra uso fora também.

Comment: Desculpa se me expliquei mal, não queremos ter regras especificas, ok. Os programadores da comunidade PRIMAVERA devem seguir as regras do SOpt, apenas fiz uma compilação das basicas do SOpt e disponibilizei em https://developers.primaverabss.com. Mais como te disse o Teams não é solução porque esta comunidade é externa à empresa e são centenas de utilizadores em vários países e para mais o teams não é para isso. Concluindo teans é para as nossas equipas internas e o SOpt é para a comunidade externa que usa a tecnologia.

Comment: O Teams é justamente para isto.

Comment: @Maneiro mais uma vez, diz-me, a equipa que está a desenvolver o .NET CORE debate aqui abertamente duvidas relacionadas com o desenvolvimento da propria FW? Ou a tag que aqui existe é usada para aqueles que usam a tecnologia se possam ajudar? O nosso caso é igual.
PS: Desculpa chatear.

Comment: Não, é exatamente o oposto. Ninguém está falando para vocês discutirem algo interno aqui, apenas que se querem dar suporte para usuários de um produto específico deveria usar o Teams. Compre as licenças necessárias e distribua para as pessoas. O time do .NET Core não vem reclamar de abuso de moderadores por fechar perguntas ruins, as pessoas do .NET Core não estão preocupadas como os usuários estão obtendo informação, mas se elas vão no SO essas pessoas devem seguir o que for determinado ali. Perguntas ruins do .NET Core ou do Primavera são fechadas igualmente.

Comment: Não queremos dar dar suporte à tecnologia/produto, temos canais especificos para isso. Queremos usar o SOpt para que os programdores externos possam obter ajuda da comunidade.  O teamns não é solução, não sei bem quem são os programadores, quando chegam ou deixam de usar a tecnologia, epara além do mais comprar centenas ou milhares de licenças teams não é viavél.
Quanto à "reclamação" e do exemplo que dei, foi porque me pareçeu que aquela questão assim como outras estavam bem (não tenho acesso ao histórico), nada contra a moderação do site. Regras são para cumprir.

Comment: @Manieiro: Obrigado pelo teu tempo nesta troca de opiniões.